In AWS, how to reach support to make a Bedrock model available?
In AWS, how to reach support to make a Bedrock model available? In the Model access/Base models list, if the model has Access status "Unavialble" and you hover over the status, the link in the hint leads to https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home?region=us-east-1/case/create but I'm not sure where to follow next.

The following parameters must be selected in "Create case" window:
Account and billing
Service: Account Activation
Category: Bedrock Allowlisting
Severity: General question
